# Using a comma before a subordinate clause

Tags: commas, subordinate-clauses

It is very common that we don't insert a comma before a subordinate clause    at end position as follows:

> The President was opening a new university ***when a bomb went off***.

However, I came across the same construction with a comma:

> The President was opening a new university, ***when a bomb went off***.

My question is, what is the function of the comma in the above construction?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [this webpage about main and subordinate clauses](https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-is-a-clause), you can easily see how the comma in your second example turns the first part of the sentence into the subordinate clause rather than the last part.

In your example:

> The President was opening a new university, **when a bomb went off**.

The fact that a bomb went off is your main point of discussion.  The fact that the President was opening a new university is incidental.

In your first example you are talking about the incident as a whole (where did the bomb go off?).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this...

> *The person was eating a sandwich when a phone rang.*

This sentence indicates to the reader what the person was doing and something that happened at that moment.

Subject 1: the person

Subject 2: the phone

> *The person was eating a sandwich, when a phone rang.*

This sentence indicates to the reader that these are two separate events happening to the subject.

Subject 1: the person.